# MongoDB - Update a just created element in an array (aggregation)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I have these schemas:

```js
Item = {
  name: String,
  price: Number;
}

Sales = {
  items: [Item],
  totalSaleValue: Number,
}

Clients = {
  clientName: String,
  sales: [Sales]
}
```

Every time a sale is inserted or updated its `totalSaleValue` field should be calculated (or re-calculated if it's an update) based in the price field from each item in the `items` field.

So when posting a new sale I'm starting this way:

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpate(
  { _id: <the _id for the client> },
  [
    { $set: { sales: { $concatArray: [ '$sales', [ /*a Sales object*/ ] ] } } }
  ]
)
```

That would effectivelly insert the new sale into the `sales` array, but I don't know how to access that just created sale to set its `totalSaleValue` field, I'm thinking something along these lines:

1. Access the `sales` field.
2. Access the last element in that array.
3. Set the `totalSaleValue` field to the $sum of the prices of all items in that sale.

How can I accomplish this, or is there a better way? I need to do this is one query

Comment: If you remove the outermost curly brackets on the second argument (so that you are passing an array as the second argument) does it work?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo on the OP, will fix it right now

Answer (score 0):

Use a second `$set` stage with `$sum` to add up the prices.